# How to append HTML elements with jQuery without duplication? (from AJAX response)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, request

So I have an Ajax request, which based on map bounds, gets HTML response of Bootstrap cards in DIV. Every time map is dragged the Ajax gets its position and appends the result to the div which is on the left side (col-6) and map is right side (col-6). How to set a condition where the elements wont be duplicated when the map is dragged where the position is already been inserted? Thank you very much!

**Response:**
div class="card property-card with-overlay v3" data-lng="15.336051956523716" data-lat="44.63806097802354" appid="4">

div class="card property-card with-overlay v3" data-lng="15.236051956523716" data-lat="44.03806097802354" appid="5">

**Function:**
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {

```
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var getNElng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng(); //max
    var getSWlng = bounds.getSouthWest().lng(); //min

    var getNElat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat(); //max
    var getSWlat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat(); //min
    $.ajax({

        //get the data from the html based on map bounds
        url: '/property/ajax/html?range_lng=' + getSWlng + '|' + getNElng + '&range_lat=' + getSWlat + '|' + getNElat,

        success: function (r, status, jqXHR) {
          
            if (status == 'success') {     
                var response = $(r);

                var locations = [];
                var markers = [];


                  // MY QUESTION PART
                 //save response html to an variable
                let result = response.find("[data-lat]").each((i, e) => {
                    var lat = $(e).data("lat");
                    var lng = $(e).data("lng");
                });
                
                //append the results to the DIV with id load-wrapper
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                $('#load-wrapper').append(result[i]);
                }



                let result2 = response.find("[data-lat]").map((i, e) => {
                    return {
                        lat: $(e).data("lat"),
                        lng: $(e).data("lng")
                    }
                }).toArray();

                for (var i = 0; i < result2.length; i++) {
                    var lo = result2[i].lng;
                    var la = result2[i].lat;
                    locations.push([la, lo])
                }

                // console.log(result);
                // console.log(locations);

                //fill marker with data from locations and fill all markers to markers array
                for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
                        // icon: icons[locations[i][2]].icon,
                        map: map,
                        // title: "property-"+(locations[i][3]),
                    });
                    markers.push(marker);
                }

            } else {
                console.log(status);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Do the items in response have any sort of unique identifier? Show a small sample of the response

Comment: Also would it be simpler to just empty the prior set before you start appending the new set with `$('#load-wrapper').empty()`?

Comment: <div class="card property-card with-overlay v3" data-lng="15.236051956523716" data-lat="44.03806097802354" appid="5">

Comment: So are those `appid` unique? [Edit] the question with your clarifications

Comment: actually no, the parent div has UniqueID = class= property-[i] but I can add unique ID to this DIV no problem

Comment: Well having a unique identifier would simplify comparing, or you could just empty the container and replace with all new ones. Not enough known as to which approach is better. Replacing also means order is maintained as sent from server

Comment: Thank you will try it out ! :)